# return value from inside flask function

Tags: python, flask

I would like to know how to return the variable input in the following example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
   if request.method == "POST":
      req = request.form
      input = req["usr_input"]         
  
   def value():
       return input
   return render_template('index.html')
```

When I try this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
   if request.method == "POST":
      req = request.form
      input = req["usr_input"]         
  
   def value():
       return input
   return render_template('index.html')

input = value()
```

It doesn't work. When I try this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
   if request.method == "POST":
      req = request.form
      input = req["usr_input"]         
  
   def value():
       return input
   return render_template('index.html')

input = index()
```

I get a runtime error.

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Does anyone know how to return the input and render template?

Comment: dont use `input` as a variable name. It is a builtin function

Comment: At the point where you are trying to assign a value to your `input` variable, there is *no conceivable value* that you could meaningfully assign to it.  The index page has not been visited yet, and indeed may never be visited during this particular run of your server.  The one place where a value from the `"usr_input"` field actually exists is inside `index()`; you need to do whatever is appropriate for this value either inside that function, or called from that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to the previous answer , but a simpler way to execute it .

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
   if request.method == "POST":
      req = request.form
      input = req["usr_input"]
      return input
   else :
      return render_template('index.html')
```

This function will only return the value if the Form is submitted  (POST method). If not , it will just show the  index.html page (GET Method)

Comment: I want to know how to call the variable input from outside the index function.

Comment: You can use the same logic for that, outside the function . Just use `user_input = session['age']` and perform whatever calculation you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Flask route functions requires a return value and you set to render_template therefore you have to choose one to return only

```py
from flask import jsonify, request
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
     input_val = request.form.get('input_val', default=0.85, type=float)

     return jsonify({'input_val': input_val})
```

Comment: can you please explain your solution and how I could return both.